# Problem to connect OpenFOAM with Paraview (cannot execuete paraFoam and touch function

Tags: paraview, openfoam

I got a problem of installing Paraview due to an error:

```
$ ParaFoam
Invalid $PV_PLUGIN_PATH and -plugin-path= not defined
No supplementary ParaView/OpenFOAM reader modules
Using builtin reader: ParaFoam -vtk

Created temporary 'cavity.foam'
/home/ofuser/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2112/bin/ParaFoam: line 423: paraview: command not found
```

I am using windows version OpenFOAM-v2112-MSYS2-Terminal.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Install a regular paraview binary (windows) and use that. There isn't any reason to use the paraFoam script.
See the [paraview FAQ answer](https://discourse.paraview.org/t/i-want-to-visualize-my-openfoam-simulation-results-with-paraview-but-im-confused-which-version-should-i-use/) on https://discourse.paraview.org and the [plugin wiki](https://develop.openfoam.com/Development/openfoam/-/wikis/modules/visualization)